# Show if the estimator is unbiased

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Suppose that the random variables $Y_1... Y_n$ satisfy
$Y_i = \beta x_i + ϵ_i$   ,   i = 1...n
where $x_i$ are fixed constants and the $ϵ_i$ are iid Normally distributed random variables with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$

I need to show if the estimator $$\beta_a = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$
is an unbiased estimator of $\beta$ or not. 
I understand that I have to show that $E(\beta_a) = \beta$ for $\beta_a $ to be an unbiased estimator of $\beta$. I have first simplified $\beta_a$ by replacing $Y_i$ with $\beta x_i + ϵ_i$ ,used some basic summation properties and took $E(\beta_a) $and arrived at the following equation: 
$$E(\beta_a) = \beta + \frac{E(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iϵ_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$

Not sure how to proceed after this. 
I also need to find the variance of the estimator $\beta_a$.

Comment: The numerator in the second equation should have $\epsilon_i$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize, it was a typo. I have edited it. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: What's $x$? It looks like you probably mean $x_i$ where it says $x$ in the denominators?

Comment: You can't find the variance without knowing the covariances of the $Y_i$.  Perhaps you forgot to state the premise that they're independent?

Comment: Thanks, yes I forgot the subscript i's for the x. No there is no premise that $Y_i$' s are independent.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that the $\epsilon_i$ are assumed to be independent. That of course makes the $Y_i$ independent.

Answer (score 1):

By [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity),

$$
E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\epsilon_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iE\left(\epsilon_i\right)=0\;.
$$

Comment: How does $\sum_{i=1}^n E( x_iϵ_i )= \sum_{i=1}^n x_iE(ϵ_i)$ ?

Comment: @StatQ $x_i$ is a fixed constant. For every fixed constant $c$ and random variable $X$ we have $\mathbb EcX=c\mathbb EX$ (if the mean exists, of course).

Comment: @drhab Thanks, I should have realized that. Got confused because of the subscript i.

Answer (score 0):

Since $E(\beta_a) = \beta $ from first part, I have managed to find the solution to the variance. I used the equation $$Var(\beta_a) = E(\beta_a^2) - (E(\beta_s))^2 = E(\beta_a^2) -  \beta^2$$ and using summation rules + expectation rules ended up with the solution: 
$Var(\beta_a) =  \sigma^2$

Please correct me if wrong. Thanks

Comment: As I noted under the question, you cannot know the variance without knowing the covariances of the $Y_i$ (or equivalently the $\epsilon_i$) or making an assumption about their independence. The term $E\left(\beta_a^2\right)$ depends on these covariances.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. According to the question the $ϵ_i$'s are independent (iid). It does not state independence of $Y_i$'s. However, since Y depends on $x_i$'s and $ϵ_i$'s only, where $x_i$'s are constant and $ϵ_i$'s are independent, does this not make $Y_i$'s independent?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd overlooked that the question does state that the $\epsilon_i$ are independent. Yes, that does make the $Y_i$ independent.

Comment: I think you're missing a factor of $\sum x_i^2$ in the denominator. There are two of those in the denominator and only one in the numerator. Also intuitively, it makes sense that the estimator for $\beta$ will be more uncertain the smaller the $x_i$ -- in the extreme case $x_i\to0$, you know almost nothing about $\beta$ and your estimator is merely amplifying the fluctuations in the $\epsilon_i$.

Comment: @joriki Got it!! I had missed squaring the denominator in one of the intermediate steps. Yes it makes sense.. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties of expectations: You can write the numerator as $E[\sum_{I=1}^{n}x_i\epsilon]=\sum_{I=1}^{n}x_iE[\epsilon]$. Now since mean is the expectation and mean of the noise or $\epsilon$ is $0$, hence the numerator is $0$.

So, we get $E[\beta_a]=\beta$. This suggests that the estimator is unbiased. Let us now try to find the variance.

Note that the variance is given by $E[(\beta-\beta_a)(\beta-\beta_a)^T]$, so we can write this as $E[\beta^T\beta-\beta^T\beta_a-\beta_a^T\beta+\beta_a^T\beta_a]$.

Now, since this is a problem of linear regression, we substitute $\beta_a=X^{+}Y = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ and $Y=\beta X+\epsilon$, then we have,
$E[\beta^T\beta-\beta^T((X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\beta X+\epsilon))-((X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\beta X+\epsilon))^T\beta+((X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\beta X+\epsilon))^T((X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\beta X+\epsilon))]$.

This gives us variance as $E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon \epsilon^T  X(X^TX)^{-1}]$ and by using the fact that $\epsilon\epsilon^T=\sigma^2$, we get $Var(\beta_a)=(X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2$.